# Intermediate completion handler not waiting for asynchronous method to finish

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, mapkit

I'm using an intermediate handler to wait for `reverseGeocodeLocation` to get a response so I can update a global variable for use in a future view controller. Even after using an intermediate completion handler in the function that contains `reverseGeocodeLocation` the main queue is going ahead of the method call.

```
func getReversedGeocodeLocation(completionHandler: (String, NSError?) ->()){
    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(newAddressLocation, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in


        if error != nil {
            print("Reverse geocoder failed with error" + error!.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        else if placemarks?.count > 0 {
            print("reverseGeocode success")
        }
        else {
            print("Problem with the data received from geocoder")
        }

        completionHandler(placemarks!.first!.name! ?? "", error)

    })
}
```

And the call for `getReversedGeocodeLocation`:

```
getReversedGeocodeLocation() { address, error in
            if address != "" {
                self.newAddress = address //newAddress is the variable 
                                          //I need to update
            }

        }
```

Comment: What do you mean "the main queue is going ahead of the method call"?

Comment: Async is async, regardless of how deeply you nest the calls.  You're going to need a semaphore to make it wait.

Comment: What's the most up to date documentation for it? I was reading somewhere it's deprecated.